# 'module not callable' when object is converted to string

Tags: python, discord

I'm using an extension for python 3.5 that makes it capable of working with the Discord API for communicating with users as a chatbot.

The extension adds a few objects to python, including the Channel object, which holds the unique ID of a channel.

In this snippet of code;

```
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author==bot.user or message.channel!=CHANNEL:
    print("Either not replying to myself, or recieved message from the wrong channel; '"+string(message.channel)+"' when I was expecting '"+(CHANNEL)+"'...")
    return
```

For some context, `CHANNEL` is a constant that is set to the target channel that I want the bot to interface with, `bot` is the connection to the server and `bot.user` is a Member object that contains the ID of the chatbot.

The if statement works fine, but when converting message.channel to a string, the following error is shown; `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. Why is this?

I can provide more details if this doesn't make sense, the API reference is also [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel).

EDIT: A little more context provided.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have somewhere in your code a statement like `import string`, and then you are trying `string(message.channel)`, which is where this exception is being raised because you cannot call the module `string` like a function.

Here is an example:

```
>>> import string
>>> string('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

In your code, try something simpler, by formatting your message thus:

```
msg = "Either not replying to myself, or received message from the wrong channel; '{}' when I was expecting '{}'..."
print(msg.format(message.channel, CHANNEL))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer, this only applies to people using discord.py;

Turns out that Channel variables can't be directly compared to one another; I had to use `message.channel.id != CHANNEL.id` to make things play nice.